# Display meta box on front end

Tags: metabox, tabs

I'm trying to add a meta box into a custom post type and display the text on the front end.

I made a meta box as follows:

```
array(
    'name'   => __( '<b>Schema</b>', 'themeum-soccer'),
    'id'     => 'schema_group',
    'type'   => 'group',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => __('schema', 'themeum-soccer'),
            'id'   => 'schema_knvb',
            'desc' => __('Paste hier de php snippit', 'themeum-soccer' ),
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'std'  => '',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => __( 'Naam Trainer', 'themeum-soccer' ),
            'id'   => "test123",
            'desc' => __( 'Naam Trainer(ex: Arno Kuppen)', 'themeum-soccer' ),
            'type' => 'text',
            'std'  => '',
        ),
    )
```

That is now saved in the plugin I'm working in, but when I put the following code in my custom post template:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class= "tab-pane fade" id="schema">
    <div>
        <?php echo rwmb_meta( $schema_knvb ); ?>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Why does it only print "Array" (see image below)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
$schema_group = rwmb_meta( 'schema_group' );
$schema_knvb = isset( $schema_group['schema_knvb'] ) ? $schema_group['schema_knvb'] : '';
echo $schema_knvb;
```

for more detail check the "Meta Box Group" page on the plugin documentation https://metabox.io/docs/meta-box-group/#section-how-to-get-meta-value-of-a-sub-field

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please do not forget mark it as accepted ; )